# How to match *anything* until a delimiter is encountered in RE-flex lexer?

Tags: regex, lexer, parser-generator, reflex

I was using [RE/flex lexer](https://www.genivia.com/doc/reflex/html) for my project. In that, I want to match the syntax corresponding to `('*)".*?"\1`. For eg, it should match `"foo"`, `''"bar"''`, but should not match `''"baz"'`.

But RE/flex matcher doesn't work with lookaheads, lookbehinds and backreferences. So, is there a correct way to match this using reflex matcher? The nearest I could achieve was the following lexer:

```
%x STRING

%%

'*\" {
    textLen = 0uz;
    quoteLen = size();
    start(STRING);
}

<STRING> {

\"'* {
    if (size() - textLen < quoteLen) goto MORE_TEXT;
    matcher().less(textLen + quoteLen);
    start(INITIAL);
    res = std::string{matcher().begin(), textLen};
    return TokenKind::STR;
}

[^"]* {
    MORE_TEXT:
    textLen = size();
    matcher().more();
}

<<EOF>> {
    std::cerr << "Lexical error: Unterminated 'STRING' \n";
    return TokenKind::ERR;
}

}

%%
```

The meta-character `.` in RE-flex matches any character, be it valid or invalid UTF8 sequence. Whereas the inverted character class - `[^...]` - matches only valid UTF8 sequences that are absent in the character class.

So, the problem with above lexer is that, it matches only valid UTF8 sequences inside strings. Whereas, I want it to match anything inside string until the delimiter.

I considered three workarounds. But all three seems to have some issues.

1. Use `skip()`. This skips all characters till it reaches delimiter. But in the process, it consumes all the string content. I don't get to keep them.
2. Use `.*?/\"` instead of `[^"]*`. This works for every properly terminated strings. But gets the lexer jammed if the string is not terminated.
3. Use consume string content character by character using `.`. Since `.` is synchronizing, it can even match invalid UTF8 sequences. But this approach feels way too slow.

So is there any better approach for solving this?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found any proper way to solve the problem. But I just did a dirty hack with 2nd workaround mentioned above.

Instead of RE/flex generated scanner loop, I added a custom loop inside string begin rule. In there, instead of failing with `scanner jammed` error, I am flushing remaining text and displaying `unterminated string` error message.

```
%x STRING

%%

'*\" {
    auto textLen = 0uz;
    const auto quoteLen = size();
    matcher().pattern(PATTERN_STRING);

    while (true) {
        switch (matcher().scan()) {

        case 1:
            if (size() - textLen < quoteLen) break;
            matcher().less(textLen + quoteLen);
            res = std::string{matcher().begin(), textLen};
            return TokenKind::STR;

        case 0:
            if (!matcher().at_end()) matcher().set_end(true);
            std::cerr << "Lexical error: Unterminated 'STRING' \n";
            return TokenKind::ERR;

        default:
            std::unreachable();

        case 2:;
        }

        textLen = size();
        matcher().more();
    }
}

<STRING>{
\"'* |
.*?/\" |
<<EOF>> std::unreachable();
}

%%
```